# Enable and Disable a Span class based on an even in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span class which should be hidden initially and visible after an event.

```
<span class="badge badge-xs badge-danger">2</span>
```

I need it to happen on the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified", "#history", function () {
    //add code to make span class visible
});
</script>
```

Wht i need is to make the class hidden on page load and make it visible after a change in #history id in a paragraph..

How is it possible through jQuery ??

Comment: you want to show and hide ? or you enabled and disabled ?

Comment: A span can't be disabled or enabled. Are you talking about making it visible/invisible?

Comment: You typically disable form elements, what do you mean exactly with enable/disable a span. Maybe you want to give it  a 'disabled' look? or make the text not selectable?

Comment: I tried:<script>
$("span.badge").prop('disabled', true);
$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified", "#history", function () {
    $("span.badge").prop('disabled', false);
});
</script>

Comment: What behavior do you expect from a "disabled" span?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.show()` and `.hide()` to change an element visibility.

```
$("span.badge").hide(); // or make it hidden in css by default

$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified", "#history", function () {
    $("span.badge").show();
});
```

The property `disabled` are used on input type fields only, for example in a text field you wouldn't be able to type in it. But in a span it has no effect since you can't input anything by default.

Answer (score 0):

For custom Events, you have two Options:

1. Work with Observer. You have one subscriber and a notifier.

   ```
   function Observer(){
       var subscriber = [];
       return{
           addSubscriber: function(func){
               subscriber.push(func);
           },
           notify: function(){
               for(var i = 0; i < subscriber.length; i++){
                   subscriber[i]();            
               }
           }
       }
   }

   var observer = new Observer();

   function calledOnEvent(){
       $(element).hide();
   }

   observer.addSubscriber(calledOnEvent);

   function createTheEvent(){
       //Logic
       observer.notify();
   }
   ```
2. You can use eventListener and the customEvent Object.

   ```
   document.addEventListener('event', aFunction);

   function createAEvent(){
       var event = new Event('event');
       document.dispatchEvent(event);
   }
   ```

In pure Javascript is the support for customEvent not really good. jQuery has a wrapper for this .trigger(): http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Thanks..I know that the DOMSubtreeModified event is deprecated. But being a newbie i can't understand how to use mutation observers in my code ??